# What meaning of this formal definition? (inner products)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to get into inner product of Hilbert spaces but I have felt stuck behind this logic of "[linearity in first slot](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Book%3A_Linear_Algebra_(Schilling_Nachtergaele_and_Lankham)/09%3A_Inner_product_spaces/9.01%3A_Inner_Products)".

"Linearity in first slot: ⟨u+v,w⟩=⟨u,w⟩+⟨v,w⟩ and ⟨au,v⟩=a⟨u,v⟩ for all u,v,w∈V and a∈F;"

But even more, I can't understand this formal definition:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9CaF.jpg

I have tried to find some description of these elements on math online resources, but failed. Every element seems strange to me except brackets, F spaces and cross-product of vectors.

Comment: If you don't understand words like "map" then you need to slow down, forget Hilbert spaces, and begin at the beginning.

Comment: @Kai It might help for you to go through an example. Can you show that the dot-product over $\Bbb R^n$ satisfies any of these requirements?